# Difference between WithEvents (Handles) vs AddHandler

Tags: vb.net, event-handling

I've searched for the difference about the use of the keyword [Handles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k46st1y.aspx) instead of [AddHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx), in [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET), but I'm unable to explain why this code doesn't work..

```
Imports System.Threading
Public Class MyClass_EventArgs
    Inherits System.EventArgs
End Class

Public Class MyClass
    Public Event MainThreadFinished(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MyClass_EventArgs)
    Private WithEvents MyEvents As MyClass
    Private trd As Thread
    Public Sub New()
        'AddHandler MainThreadFinished, AddressOf Me.MyEvents_ThreadFinished
        trd = New Thread(AddressOf mainThread)
        trd.IsBackground = True
        trd.Start()
        RaiseEvent MainThreadFinished(Me, Nothing)
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        trd.Abort()
    End Sub
    Protected Sub MyEvents_ThreadFinished(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MyClass_EventArgs) _
                Handles MyEvents.MainThreadFinished
        MessageBox.Show("AAA")
    End Sub
    Private Sub mainThread()
        RaiseEvent MainThreadFinished(Me, Nothing)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Well, this code never respond to the events, but if I uncomment the followin line, the code works and the messagebox appear...

```
'AddHandler MainThreadFinished, AddressOf Me.MyEvents_ThreadFinished
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: You are trying to listen to your *own* event.  Doesn't make sense, some *other* class would be interested in your event.  The vb compiler only implements the senseful use of Handles.  Use a virtual method if this pattern is desired.

Comment: yes, you are right, this is not a good implementation, but I wrote this for test the event system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you've made a fine discovery! Per Microsoft documentation, *[RaiseEvent Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwd3bwed%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)*,

> Non-shared events should not be raised within the constructor of the
>   class in which they are declared. Although such events do not cause
>   run-time errors, they may fail to be caught by associated event
>   handlers. Use the `Shared` modifier to create a shared event if you need
>   to raise an event from a constructor.

In other words, Microsoft says you shouldn't be doing what you're doing - and if you must, to use shared events.

In looking through other sources, I would say that the difference between `AddHandler` and `Handles` is a matter of syntactic sugar. You may want to look into how events are done in C# for more insight (such as in *[C# Events](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/C-Sharp-events/)*). `Handles` is used in conjunction with `WithEvents` as a way for an instance of a class to automatically subscribe to events (which is otherwise explicitly done with `+=` in C# and with `AddHander` in VB.NET).

It would seem that your explicit `AddHandler` ensures that the event hookups are in place before the `RaiseEvent`, and so then it works as you wanted. I can only guess that without that, those event hookups weren't yet done - that is, it didn't work because of however the compiler inserts the code that performs the equivalent of AddHandler behind the scenes, by whatever design pattern the compiler writers deemed as appropriate. It would seem that the designers were well aware of this possible consequence, given their warning about this.

Comment: Hey man, do you know any good resources where I can find good content like this? I find it hard to understand events in VB.net where I have to use WithEvents, RaiseEvents, AddHandler and other things. What I'm trying to do is transfer data from one User Control's textbox by a click of a button to another User Control and I couldn't find any tutorials out there that can demonstrate this.

Comment: @Carnal: An Event is just another way to implement a "callback" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming) ). It's a way to let your class be interactive with other classes. You define Events in your class, and at critical or interesting points in your class, your code uses `RaiseEvent` to let the other classes respond to those critical or interesting moments. The other classes subscribe to whichever events that are defined in your class, either automatically (`WithEvents` and `Handles`) or explicitly (`AddHandler`).

Comment: @Carnal: Subscribing means this: Some other class passes in a `Delegate` (the .NET equivalent for a function pointer) to your class for a particular Event defined within your class; this Delegate is going to be to some `Function` or `Sub` in the other class. When your class does the `RaiseEvent` thing, it will call every `Delegate` that got passed in to it by other classes. When there's more than one Delegate, it will call each in turn, one at a time (in potentially arbitrary order). When there are no Delegates, nothing happens.