# Is WithEvents any different from AddHandler?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, .net-3.5, asp.net-3.5

Probably not a very good question, bit of a noob question, but anyway...

I am coding a HttpModule as below and looking at many examples online, unfortunately they are all in C#. They all seem to be using AddHandler to hook methods up to events.

**Question: is using WithEvents as below any different from using AddHandler, particularly in terms of code safety?**

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI    
Public Class MyModule1
    Implements IHttpModule    
    Private WithEvents _context As HttpApplication
    Private WithEvents _page As Page    
    ' <summary>
    '  You will need to configure this module in the web.config file of your
    '  web and register it with IIS before being able to use it. For more information
    '  see the following link: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=8101007
    ' </summary>
#Region "IHttpModule Members"    
    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IHttpModule.Dispose    
        ' Clean-up code here    
    End Sub

    Public Sub Init(ByVal context As HttpApplication) Implements IHttpModule.Init
        _context = context
    End Sub    
#End Region

    Public Sub OnLogRequest(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles _context.LogRequest    
        ' Handles the LogRequest event to provide a custom logging 
        ' implementation for it    
    End Sub

    Private Sub _context_PreRequestHandlerExecute(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles _context.PreRequestHandlerExecute    
        Dim page As Page = TryCast(_context.Context.CurrentHandler, Page)    
        If Not page Is Nothing Then _page = page    
    End Sub

    Private Sub _page_Init(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles _page.Init    
        'Does this affect Inits coded elsewhere?    
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Possibly related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123824/difference-between-withevents-handles-vs-addhandler?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, that question is helpful but focuses more on "why isn't this working" as opposed to a definitive "the differences are..." etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK - There is no functional difference. `WithEvents` is just a short-cut to Adding and Removing method handlers manually.

If anything `WithEvents` is "safer" because you don't have to remember to call `RemoveHandler` afterwards, but really there is no other difference.

So to clarify you ***either*** have an object declared `WithEvents`, and each event Has a `Handles xxx` after it:

```
Private WithEvents Button1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

End Sub
```

***Or*** you define the event methods and call `AddHandler`

```
Private Button1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf Button1_Click
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 'No Handles Here

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, so if the ASPX page already has an Init the one coded in the HTTP Module above is not over-writing it? Both will be called not just one?

Comment: If you call `AddHandler` on a method that already has `Handles xxx`, it will get called twice when that event fires.

Comment: Ok I don't need to worry then! Not that it matters but in my example above would the Init in the ASPX get called first or the Init in my HTTP Module?